# How to set jquery modal to show every 3 days with cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I built a modal that I want to show every 3 days. I installed the jquery cookie plugin from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie and have set up a test, but it always shows that the cookie exists even though it's set to expire after 5 seconds. What am I doing wrong?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

$.cookie('modal', '1', { expires: 5000 });

if( $.cookie('modal') === null ) {  // if expired / non-existent
    alert('not exists');
}
else{
    alert('exists');
}   
});
```

NEW CODE

```
if($.cookie('modal') == null){
    alert('not exists');
    $.cookie('modal', '1', { expires: 3 });     
}   
else{
    alert('exists');
}
```

Comment: the expires number is in days (as i remember), not in seconds/minutes

Comment: If that is the code you run when you test, the cookie is created every time and will exist when it gets to the checks.

Comment: I would advise storing the Date and or Time in the cookie, when it's created. Then when the user returns, if the difference is more than 3 days, reset the date time and display the Modal.

Comment: @JarlikStepsto You're correct. It's mentioned in the second example at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: as mjuopperi wrote, you should create the cookie only if it not exists and the expire attribute is in days (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/tree/v2.1.0#readme). Save the creation date

Comment: Got it @JarlikStepsto. I added new code to the original post. Does look right? I want the modal to show once every 3 days.

Comment: yes, that looks right. but i think it would be better, to save the timestamp as value of the cookie and check it. (is cookie set -> is current timestamp - saved timestamp >= 3 days -> show dialog, update cookie, to new timestamp)